# How to change background color depending on trial?

Tags: javascript, css, background, background-color

I am quite new to JsPsych and I wonder how I can change the background color within my experiment depending on the trial. I implemented an instruction trial and a practice trial, consisting of an encoding and a recall trial. I'd like the background color of the instruction phase to be #BFBFBF and the background color of the practice phase (encoding and recall trial) to be #green.

I've tried to implement two different stylesheets, to use the "document.body.style.backgroundColor"-function and to create different classes, but every time only one (mostly the last) color is displayed.

This is my actual code (currently I have defined the background color via the body-element):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Instruktionen</title>
        <script src="jspsych-6.1.0/jspsych.js"></script>
        <script src="jspsych-6.1.0/plugins/jspsych-html-keyboard-response.js"></script>
        <script src="jspsych-6.1.0/plugins/jspsych-instructions.js"></script>
        <script src="jspsych-6.1.0/plugins/ComplexSpanWM_jspsych-image-mouse-response.js"></script>
        <script src="jspsych-6.1.0/plugins/jspsych-html-button-response.js"></script>
        <link href="jspsych-6.1.0/css/jspsych.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body style=background-color:#BFBFBF>
    </body>
    <script>
    
    var timeline = [];
    
    /////////////////////////////// INSTRUCTION PHASE ///////////////////////////////
    var instructions_1_to_4 = {
        type: 'instructions',
        pages: [
            '<p><strong>Herzlich Willkommen bei der Merkaufgabe: Tiere merken.</p>',

            // instruction page 1
            '<p><strong>Die Aufgabe besteht aus zwei wichtigen Teilen:</p>' +
            '<p>Zuerst müssen Sie entscheiden, ob ein gezeigtes Tier auf den Füßen oder auf dem Kopf steht.</strong></p>' +
            '<p>Wenn das Tier auf den Füßen steht, drücken Sie die rechte Maustaste.' +
            '<p>Wenn das Tier auf dem Kopf steht, drücken Sie die linke Maustaste.</p>' +
            '<p>Zur Erinnerung sehen Sie rechts einen grünen und links einen roten Mann, dies sind aber keine Boxen zum Anklicken! Ihre Antwort erfolgt allein über die Maustaste.</p>' +
            '<p>Sobald Sie eine Maustaste geklickt haben, erscheint das nächste Tier.</p>' +
            '<img src="Stimuli/instruction1.jpg" width="500" height="300" ></img>',

            // instruction page 2
            '<p><strong>Der zweite Teil der Aufgabe ist genauso wichtig:</p>' +
            '<p>Merken Sie sich die Reihenfolge, in der die Tiere gezeigt werden.</strong></p>' +
            '<p>Sobald Sie diesen Bildschirm sehen, klicken Sie mit der Maus auf die Tiere in der Reihenfolge, in der Sie angezeigt wurden.' +
            '<p>Ob das Tier auf dem Kopf oder auf den Füßen stand, ist dabei egal.' +
            '<p>Sobald Sie auf ein Tier klicken, erscheint die Antwort. Sie können ihre Antwort nicht mehr korrigieren.</p>' +
            '<img src="Stimuli/instruction2.jpg" width="500" height="300" ></img>' ,

            // instruction page 3
            '<p><strong>Das Ziel ist es, möglichst viele Punkte zu erspielen.</strong></p>' +
            '<p>Für richtige Antworten werden Punkte gesammelt.</p>' +
            '<p>Bei falschen oder zu langsamen Antworten gibt es keine Punkte.</p>' +
            '<p>Zusätzlich sehen Sie nach jedem Durchgang einen Highscore. Das ist die Anzahl an Tieren, die Sie sich in der richtigen Reihenfolge merken konnten. Im Laufe der Aufgaben werden es immer mehr Tiere und es ist ganz normal, dabei Fehler zu machen.</p>',

            // instruction page 4
            '<p>Bitte antworten Sie so schnell und so korrekt wie möglich!</p>' +
            '<p>Beginnen wir mit Probe-Durchgängen zur Übung</p>'
        ],

        show_clickable_nav: true,
        button_label_next: 'Weiter',
        allow_backward: false,
        allow_keys: false,
        post_trial_gap: 1
    }
    timeline.push(instructions_1_to_4);

    /////////////////////////////// PRACTICE PHASE ///////////////////////////////
    var images = [
        'Stimuli/cow_feet.jpg',
        'Stimuli/cow_head.jpg',
        'Stimuli/dog_feet.jpg',
        'Stimuli/dog_head.jpg',
        'Stimuli/horse_feet.jpg',
        'Stimuli/horse_head.jpg',
        'Stimuli/pig_feet.jpg',
        'Stimuli/pig_head.jpg'
    ];

    // ENCODING PHASE   
    var animals = [
        { animal: 'Stimuli/cow_feet.jpg', data: {correct_response: 2} },
        { animal: 'Stimuli/cow_head.jpg', data: {correct_response: 0} },
        { animal: 'Stimuli/dog_feet.jpg', data: {correct_response: 2} },
        { animal: 'Stimuli/dog_head.jpg', data: {correct_response: 0} },
        { animal: 'Stimuli/horse_feet.jpg', data: {correct_response: 2} },
        { animal: 'Stimuli/horse_head.jpg', data: {correct_response: 0} },
        { animal: 'Stimuli/pig_feet.jpg', data: {correct_response: 2} },
        { animal: 'Stimuli/pig_head.jpg', data: {correct_response: 0} }
    ];

    var Encoding_Phase = {
        timeline: [
            {
                type: 'image-mouse-response',
                stimulus: jsPsych.timelineVariable('animal'),
                stimulus_height: 457,
                stimulus_width: 604,
                choices: [0, 2]
            }
        ],
        timeline_variables: animals,
        sample: {
            type: 'with-replacement',
            size: 2
        },
        data: {test_part: 'Encoding_Phase'}
    };

    // RECALL PHASE
    var solution1 = function() {
        var trial = jsPsych.data.get().filter({test_part: 'Encoding_Phase'});
        var displayed_animal = trial.values()[0].stimulus;
        if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/cow_feet.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/cow_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' align=left >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/dog_feet.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/dog_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' align=left >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/horse_feet.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/horse_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' align=left >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/pig_feet.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/pig_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' align=left >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/cow_head.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/cow_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' align=left >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/dog_head.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/dog_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' align=left >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/horse_head.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/horse_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' align=left >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/pig_head.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/pig_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' align=left >";
        }
    };

    var solution2 = function() {
        var trial = jsPsych.data.get().filter({test_part: 'Encoding_Phase'});
        var displayed_animal = trial.values()[1].stimulus;
        if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/cow_feet.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/cow_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/dog_feet.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/dog_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/horse_feet.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/horse_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/pig_feet.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/pig_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/cow_head.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/cow_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/dog_head.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/dog_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/horse_head.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/horse_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' >";
        } else if (displayed_animal == 'Stimuli/pig_head.jpg') {
            return "<img src='Stimuli/pig_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' >";
        }
    };
    
    var Recall_Phase = {
        timeline: [
            {
                type: 'html-button-response',
                timeline: [
                    {stimulus: '1', prompt: ''},
                    {stimulus: '2', prompt: solution1},
                    {stimulus: '2', prompt: solution2}
                ],
                choices: [  
                    "<img src='Stimuli/horse_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' >",
                    "<img src='Stimuli/pig_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' >",
                    "<img src='Stimuli/dog_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' >",
                    "<img src='Stimuli/cow_feet.jpg' width='213' height='216' >"
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    var Practice_Phase = {
        timeline: [Encoding_Phase, Recall_Phase]
    }
    timeline.push(Practice_Phase);

    jsPsych.init({
        timeline: timeline,
        preload_images: images
    })

    </script>
</html>
```

Does anyone know a command to simply use two different background colors within the same experiment?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this question and thought I'd answer, since I had to do the same thing in my experiment (change the background color in the middle of the experiment). What I did was set the background colors as functions and then add the functions as parameters, so this is what it would look like in your case:

```
function set_html_style_1() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#BFBFBF'
}

function set_html_style_2() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
}

var your_block = {
    type: 'html-keyboard-response',
    on_start: set_html_style_1,
    stimulus: 'Hello world!',
    choices: [' '],
}
```

I'd also recommend checking this discussion: https://github.com/jspsych/jsPsych/discussions/936